# Writing a formula program with a dataset

Tags: python, dataset, formula

I am trying to make a simple formula calculator in Python as a personal project because all of the Pokemon EXP gain calculators are outdated.

```
p = input("Enter the defeated Pokemon's species number: ")
le = input("Level of the defeated Pokemon: ")
lp = input("Level of the victorious Pokemon: ")
f = input("Was the Pokemon obtained from a trade? (Y/N) ");
p = int(p)
le = int(le)
lp = int(lp)
f = int(f1)

p * le
le * lp
lp * f

Y = 1.2
N = 1

n1 = 64
n2 = 142
n3 = 263
n4 = 62
n5 = 142
n6 = 267
n7 = 63
```

Error I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3b00b90525d0> in <module>()
      6 le = int(le)
      7 lp = int(lp)
----> 8 f = int(f)
      9 
     10 p * le

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Y'
```

I am having trouble defining the input to integers, and linking those integers to a dataset that contains the entire Pokedex. If someone could help me with this, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: The expected input value for `f` is either `Y` or `N` which cannot be converted to an integer as this is a char and not an integer (in either case it is a string before conversion and you should think about handling invalid user input in the next step). I assume you want to convert `N` to 1 and `Y` to 1.2 which you could do with an (inline) if statement: `f = 1.2 if f == 'Y' else 1`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to call `int()` on a string. You are having the user enter either `Y` or `N`, and then trying to convert that to an int. From the code, it looks like you are trying to have `f` equal to 1.2 if the answer is `Y`, and equal to 1 if the answer is `N`. You can do this in one line with an [`if else`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/) statement:

```py
p = input("Enter the defeated Pokemon's species number: ")
le = input("Level of the defeated Pokemon: ")
lp = input("Level of the victorious Pokemon: ")
f = input("Was the Pokemon obtained from a trade? (Y/N) ");
p = int(p)
le = int(le)
lp = int(lp)
f = 1.2 if f == "Y" else 1

p * le
le * lp
lp * f

Y = 1.2
N = 1

n1 = 64
n2 = 142
n3 = 263
n4 = 62
n5 = 142
n6 = 267
n7 = 63
```